# is it possible to run npm script from Javascript

Tags: node.js

My unbuild node.js project is on a file server and I want to execute the npm script "build" which should build the application. But I can't find a way to call this command through code. Does anyone know if this should be possible? When I try to search for a result I keep finding tutorials on how npm script work, which is not what I want to know.
Is it possble to run an npm script (command?) from code?

Comment: You may want to look at the `spawn` command under the `child_process` module in nodejs docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to execute a script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = exec("npm build", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});

dir.on('exit', function (code) {
    // return value from "npm build"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to use the child_process package, in my code completion it shows all its funtions but when I run it I get an error that the module cannot be found. Yet I think this should work if child_process could be found.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently#programmatic-usage) npm package, it allow managing your npm scripts and provides API to call npm-scripts from inside your Node app project, check programmatic-usage section.